# Regex does not match with string containing 4 groups

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match a string which I divide into 4 groups:

```
1.) group has a "-"
2.) group has any char
3.) group has a ":"
4.) group has any char
```

I have tried this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[-][.*][:][.*]*$");
bool isMatch = regex.IsMatch("-jobid:3");
```

isMatch is false.

What is wrong in my pattern?

Comment: You might also want to take a look at http://regexpal.com/. There you can get immediately feedback whether your regex works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error here is that `.*` should not be enclosed in brackets.

This:

```
[.*]
```

Means this:

- The dot
- or the asterix

This:

```
.*
```

Means this:

- Any character, zero or more times

Additionally, if there is only 1 legal character in a spot, you generally don't need to enclose it in brackets.

So try this expression instead:

```
new Regex("^-.*:.*$");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have misunderstood the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) notion. A character class is only a collection of characters without any order. So when you write something like `[.*]`, that means a literal dot **or** a literal asterisk.

An important precision, all the regex special characters loose their meaning and are seen as literal characters inside a character class. However some characters may have a special meaning in a character class like `^` at the first place (to negate a class) or `-` to define a range. Some syntaxes can be used too inside character classes, like [shorthand](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) or [POSIX character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), and [character classes substractions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html).

You can write the whole pattern without all these (useless) character classes:

```
^-.*:.*$
```

However, to be more efficient, you can use a negated character class before the semi-colon:

```
^-[^:]*:.*$
```